# How to use Editor.js with MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, next.js, editorjs

I am building a blog with `Next.js`. I am using editor.js as my editor, but I find it hard to save the `Editor.js` data in the MongoDB database.

My blog model:

```
const blogSchemma = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxLength: [120, "Room name cannot exceed 100 characters"],
    },
    post: {
      type: String,
      // required: true,
    },
    images: [
      {
        public_id: {
          type: String,
          // required: true,
        },
        url: {
          type: String,
          // required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.models.Blog || mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchemma);
```

Where I am trying to save the blog post to the data base:

```
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [post1, setPost1] = useState("");
  const [introduction, setIntroduction] = useState("");
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  const onSaveHandler = async (editorInstance) => {
      const post = await editorInstance.save();
      if (!title || title === "")
        throw new Error("Title cannot be empty. Please enter title");
      if (!post.blocks[0])
        throw new Error("Blog cannot be empty. Please enter some data");

      const blog = {
        title,
        description,
        images,
        post,
      };
      dispatch(createBlog(blog));
  };

 let blogContent;
  if (!editorTools) blogContent = <p>loading...</p>;
  else
    blogContent = (
      <EditorJs
        instanceRef={(instance) => (editorInstance = instance)}
        tools={editorTools}
        // readOnly={readOnly}
        data={post1}
        placeholder={`Let's write an awesome blog!`}
      />
    );
```

The error that I'm getting:
`"Cast to string failed for value \"{\n  time: 1631742225097,\n  blocks: [ { id: 'gKAdY5E37a', type: 'paragraph', data: [Object] } ],\n  version: '2.22.2'\n}\" (type Object) at path \"post\""`

Comment: I guess that you should `JSON.stringify()` the description (or whatever the editor state is).
editor.js will return an object and not a (HTML) string

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from the blog model
I changed from this:

```
  post: {
      type: String,
      // required: true,
    },
```

to this:

```
post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed }
```